# Cannot save data with html tags to Laravel database using axios

Tags: laravel, axios, vuejs3

I was able to save the data I entered to the database, but when saving, the axios removed the HTML tags I entered from VueEditor. I want to maintain the data with HTML tags in the database.

**VueEditor component**

```
<template>
    <vue-editor v-model="productForm.content" class="h-[10rem] mb-32"></vue-editor>
</template>

<script setup>
import { VueEditor } from "vue3-editor";
import { computed, ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const content = ref();
</script>
```

Imported component

```
<rich-text-editor label="Description" v-model="product.content" />
```

Submit func

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}
const save = async () => {
      await axios.post("products", productForm.value, config)
            .then(response => {
                notify("Product saved successfully", "success");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                notify(error.response.data.message, "error");
            });
    }
```

I logged the submitted data to the Laravel log and checked that Axios removed the HTML tags before sending text only to the Laravel database. How can I maintain it without removing the tags?

Comment: Can you please how you take the data for `productForm.value` ?

Comment: Why would you want to save the HTML as well as the data?

Comment: @Aro, it is ref reactivity like const productForm = ref({content: null })

Comment: @SiimmKahn, it is not HTML file but content with html tags like <p>text content</p> and my client wanted the product description to have bold text

Comment: I found a way using btoa to convert it to base64 before sending